# If the form (on another website displayed through an iFrame has been sent), allow the user to proceed

Tags: php, forms, api, iframe, moodle

Site 1 has a contact form.

Site 2 has content on the next page that is only accessible for guest users if they have filled out and sent the form on Site 1.

Does anyone have any ideas of how this could be accomplished?

[image]

Comment: use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to identify the sender of the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write in your php file where you receive form data

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 // do whatever you want 

     header('Location: http://www.Your_site2_address.com');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should get that ball rolling!